# Meteor server side packages debugging

Tags: debugging, meteor, node-debugger

Does anyone know of a way to debug imported server side packages in meteor?

I came across this link https://forums.meteor.com/t/vs-code-server-debugging-with-meteor-1-10/53437

I followed the instructions but it only allows me to add breakpoints on the server side code that I created. What I would like to be able to do is add a breakpoint on one of the packages that I am using for this app, eg. oauth.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package source code from Github and add it in a folder called `packages` in your root project folder. Then, your code will use the package locally, then you can debug it.

See some oficial info about packages here: https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages

This is a good way to help yourself and the community.